# Postgres wraps subquery results in parentheses

Tags: postgresql

Don't pay attention to uselessness of the provided query, it's just a simplified part of a complex one.

I run query:

```
SELECT elem FROM (SELECT id FROM data) AS elem;
```

It yields the result:

```
 elem 
------
 (5)
 (4)
 (24)
 (3)
 (23)
```

Why does each value enclosed in parentheses?

So, to fix it I do:

```
SELECT trim(elem::text, ')(') FROM (SELECT id FROM data) AS elem;
```

I have a feeling it should not be that way...

Comment: `select elem.* from ...`

Comment: Yeah, it's my stupidity))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT elem.id FROM (SELECT id FROM data) AS elem;
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE

> In PostgreSQL, a reference to a table name (or alias) in a query is
>   effectively a reference to the composite value of the table's current
>   row

and futher querying examples, also further regarding brackets:

> The external text representation of a composite value consists of
>   items that are interpreted according to the I/O conversion rules for
>   the individual field types, plus decoration that indicates the
>   composite structure. The decoration consists of parentheses (( and ))
>   around the whole value, plus commas (,) between adjacent items.

also some relevant here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS

Answer (score 1):

You select rows. Select columns instead:

```
SELECT elem FROM (SELECT id FROM data) AS tbl(elem);
```

Comment: `elem` is the table. I am not sure how this helps.