# select radius from ST_MinimumBoundingRadius

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to get just radius value from ST_MinimumBoungingRadius.
Something like this (from postgresql documentation) works just fine:

```
SELECT radius 
FROM 
ST_MinimumBoundingRadius('MULTIPOINT(1 2,3 8,5 6)')
```

So I don't understand, why doesn't work similar query on existing table:

```
SELECT radius 
FROM
(SELECT
ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(ST_Collect(geom)) minrad
FROM a) b
```

Result of this query is ERROR:  column "radius" does not exist

Is there any way to extract just radius value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main [difference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-sql.html) is that in the first case you are calling the function in the `FROM` clause while in the second it is in the `select` clause. In the first case, the result is made of two column while in the later it is a [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538515/postgres-wraps-subquery-results-in-parentheses) aggregation of all columns.

You can fix it by using the function in the `FROM` clause again, using [either](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/call-function-where-argument-is-a-subselect-statement) a double-parenthesis or a lateral join:

```
SELECT radius 
FROM ST_MinimumBoundingRadius((SELECT ST_Collect(geom) 
                                FROM a)) minrad;
```

or

```
SELECT radius
FROM (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) geom FROM a) tbla,
    LATERAL ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(tbla.geom) minrad;
```

Comment: Thanks,works just fine. One with lateral is better for me,because works with group by clause.In first one with double parentheses doesn't like that there is more rows in subqery.