# SELECT from function which returns multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following query, which clusters locations, and returns a cluster ID, along with a structure containing the raw points within that cluster:

```
SELECT
    cluster_id,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(origin)) AS points
FROM (
    SELECT
        origin,
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(origin, eps := 0.01, minPoints := 5) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS cluster_id
    FROM
        ride
    WHERE
        region_id = 1 AND
        created_at > now() - interval '1 week'
) a
WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster_id
```

Example output:

```
3   {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[ ... ]}
4   {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[ ... ]}
```

Instead of returning the raw points, I want to returning the bounding circle for the cluster (center and radius), which can be done using `ST_MinimumBoundingRadius`:

```
SELECT
    ST_AsGeoJSON(center),
    radius
FROM
    ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[ ... ]}')
    )
```

Example output:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[ ... ]}  0.002677744742706528
```

However, as `ST_MinimumBoundingRadius` returns two columns, the below throws an error:

```
SELECT
    cluster_id,
    ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(ST_Collect(origin))
FROM (
    ...
) a
WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster_id;
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853353/select-radius-from-st-minimumboundingradius) question which mentions using `LATERAL` but I wasn't able to get a working query.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try another subselect:

```
SELECT q.cluster_id,
       (q.mbr).radius,
       (q.mbr).center
FROM (
   SELECT cluster_id,
          ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(
             ST_Collect(origin)
          ) AS mbr
   FROM (
      ...
   ) AS a
) AS q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple in the end, no idea how I didn't guess this.

```
SELECT
    cluster_id,
    (ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(ST_Collect(origin))).*
FROM (
    SELECT
        origin,
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(origin, eps := 0.01, minPoints := 5) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS cluster_id
    FROM
        ride
    WHERE
        region_id = 1 AND
        created_at > now() - interval '1 week'
) a
WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cluster_id
```

Comment: This will end up calling the function twice. if you want to avoid that, wrap the query with another outer query that selects the `center` and `radius` properties.

Comment: As in `(SELECT center, radius FROM ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(bounds)).*`? This throws the same error I had before - `ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`

Comment: I mean `SELECT x.center, x.radius FROM (SELECT st_minimumboundingradius(...) AS x FROM ...) AS q`

Comment: Could you post your suggestion as an answer? I've tried your suggestion but get `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "x"`